# Difference in the number of elements of a string column before and after calculations in c#

Tags: c#, string, csv

I am calculating a new string value which is a column calculated from  four columns in the imported CSV file. These four original columns contain integers. I have done this in two ways as follows:

NB: eventParams are the columns from the imported CSV file.

The first way - here, i'm doing the calculations of the four columns and then i'm changing the results to string to get the new column:

```
float cal = float.Parse(eventParams[1]) + (float.Parse(eventParams[2]) / 60) + (float.Parse(eventParams[3]) / 3600) + (float.Parse(eventParams[4]) / 216000);

string TimeString = cal.ToString();
```

The second way - here, i'm taking directly the four columns and joining them by semi-column to get the new column:

```
 string TimeString = eventParams[1]+ ";" +eventParams[2] + ";" + eventParams[3] + ";" + eventParams[4];
```

The second ways gives me the right answer, as it takes all the values in the original CSV file. The first way seems to leave behind some values, hence I have fewer values. On top of that, the first way also seems to modify the order. I would like to use the results of the first way but without the modification of the order and also by taking all the values in the original columns (like the case in the second way).

regards.

Comment: Hard to answer your question without including how you're using the resulting `TimeString`. Furthermore, is your CSV separated by `,` or `;`? And what's the decimal separator when using `cal.ToString()`?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what your issue is.... In the first you are doing a bunch of maths, in the second you are concatenating strings. They are doing completely different things so I'm not really sure I understand what you mean by "The second way give me the right answer". If it does what is the question?

Comment: @Chris Look, Im talking about the length of the variable TimeString, for sure the values of the variable will be different but their lengths should be the same which is not in my case.

Comment: @Johnny how about including sample input values then? You're mind is right there in the context of the problem, ours isn't, so you have to help us help you.

Comment: @Johnny: Perhaps if you gave us the two strings so we could see what you are comparing it would make more sense? Currently I am struggling to understand why you would expect the two to be the same length. The first will be something like "123.45678" and the other will be something like "12;34;56;78". The values of eventParams are presumably very relevant to the problem you are having here.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Lets say I just want to save this variable in a text file later, even in this, the first method has fewer values (leaving out some values). The decimal separator is a point (.) - (changed in the CultureInfo). As to the CSV delimiter,  it is a semi-colon - but how does that relate to these operations?

Comment: @Chris, Aaah ok, I understand th issue, I might have given incomplete information, im performing this several times (in a loop). So I have for example in the first approach "1.xxx" , "2.xxx", "3.xxx", while in the second "1col1;1col2;1col3;1col4" , "2col1;2col2;2col3;2col4" ...etc. So im talking about the number of results if you will. Let me see how I can modify the question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to include the looping code in your question. Also try to include the type of all relevant variables. eg I assume the actual type of `eventParams` is a `string[]` but I may be wrong. It may not be relevant but its only a few more characters to include the info. :)

Comment: So basically the second example has more results _because_ it contains semicolons, which you have added yourself, and the first example doesn't contain semicolons because you're not adding them?